# How to know mariaDB Version from Version of 10.4.14-MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

when I check my mariaDB version , I see that I have 10.4.14-MariaDB but I know the last version is 8 so how to explain that?

Comment: MariaDB <> MySQL... They are two different products though they share a root. Some quick web research should have revealed that easily...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MariaDB 10.2, MariaDB 10.3, and MariaDB 10.4 function as limited drop-in replacements for MySQL 5.7, as far as InnoDB is concerned. However, the implementation differences continue to grow in each new MariaDB version.

> MariaDB 10.0 and MariaDB 10.1 function as limited drop-in replacements for MySQL 5.6, as far as InnoDB is concerned. However, there are some implementation differences in some features.

> MariaDB 5.5 functions as a drop-in replacement for MySQL 5.5.

> MariaDB 5.1, MariaDB 5.2, and MariaDB 5.3 function as drop-in replacements for MySQL 5.1.

[image: 1]

source: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/